# Matrix by vector multiplication along third axis

Tags: python, numpy

I am using `numpy` to perform some mathematical calculations in `Python`.
I have an `A` matrix of dimensions `(N, N)` and a vector `b` of dimension `m`.
I would like to multiply `A` by `b` so as to obtain a tensor of size `(N, N, m)`.
For example, if it were:

```
A 
1 2
3 4

b
1 2 3
```

I would like to make the product in order to obtain the tensor `C = A*b`:

```
C
1 2
3 4

2 4
6 8

3 6
9 12
```

Finally, I would like to get a `(N,N)` matrix with the maximum value of C along the third direction, that is

```
max(C)
3 6
9 12
```

is there a numpy function that allows this operation?

**Update**

if finally I want to add to each matrix `(N, N, i)` of `C` the i-th element of the vector `b`?

In the example:

```
A
1 2
3  4

b
1  2  3

C = A*b
1  2
3  4

2  4
6  8

3  6
9  12

D = C+b
2  3
4  5

4  6
8  10

6  9
12 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way leveraging [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
(b[:,None,None] * A).max(0)

array([[ 3,  6],
       [ 9, 12]])
```

---

**Update**: you can add `b` to each inner matrix with:

```
b[:,None,None] * (1+A)

array([[[ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 4,  6],
        [ 8, 10]],

       [[ 6,  9],
        [12, 15]]])
```

---

Setup:

```
A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
b = np.array([1,2,3])
```